# How can I associate two models where column values match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, foreign-keys

Let's say I have two models

ModelA: `id`, `unique_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

ModelB: `id`, `model_a_unique_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

those unique ids are strings.

How can I use such a column to associate values in these columns? There's a 1:n relation between them. I did try googling that, but I came up empty.

**Edit:** and of course by values I mean records.

Comment: So you want a relationship where ModelA `has_many` ModelB's and ModelB `belongs_to` ModelA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
class A
  has_many :bs, foreign_key: :model_a_unique_id, primary_key: :unique_id
end

class B
  belongs_to :a, foreign_key: :model_a_unique_id, primary_key: :unique_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL, you want to use a `join`. You can accomplish combining the columns of both tables using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM ModelA AS a 
    JOIN ModelB AS b ON a.unique_id = b.model_a_unique_id
```

Read more about [MySQL Joins here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: I could do this. But I'm interested in associating the records using something like belongs_to :model_a, where: 'model_a. unique_id = model_a. model_a_unique_id' - is there no way to do this?